# Getting a list of exclusive class name with a class name in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, puppeteer, webautomation

I am trying to get class names and check if at least one of the tags have `red` class or not. So, if at least one of them includes `red` class, the function must return `true`, otherwise, `false`.

The closest one is this:

```
const nodeList = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const arrynodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.an_panel_list')
    return arrynodeList
})

console.log('nodeList:', nodeList)
```

And I get

```
nodeList: { '0': {}, '1': {} }
```

For instance, the html looks like.

```
<div class="an_panel_list red">
<div class="an_panel_list">
<div class="an_panel_list">
<div class="an_panel_list">
```

And I get `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to solve everything in the `evaluate` function:

```js
const nodeList = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const arrynodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.an_panel_list');
    const redList = Array.prototype.slice.call(arrynodeList).filter(e => e.classList.contains("red"))
    return {
      divs: arrynodeList.length,
      reds: redList.length
    }
})

console.log(nodeList)
```